# when i was trying to install postgis on my mac PostgreSQL13

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgis

I have PostgresSQL13 from EDB, but when I was installing it, I could not add extension PostGIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps learn how to install pgsql using docker-machine/docker-compose. This will abstract it out of darwin and into linux where all of your problems magically disappear (and new ones start of course)

Comment: Is there any log entry to the error?